# Cannot echo .load function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

For some reason this code doesn't work. Adding \ to the front of the $ doesn't change anything. Can anyone see the problem?

```
$commentid = 2; //for example
echo "<script>";
echo "<div id = 'commentinput".$commentid."'>";
echo "</div>";

echo "$('#commentinput".$commentid."').load('editcomments2.php')";
echo "</script>";
```

Comment: Try echoing it inside a script tag

Comment: Yes it already is. @voiys

Comment: @DevsiOdedra Why not?

Comment: First of all you are missing ; after $commentid = 2; and rest has been told in the answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
echo '$("#commentinput'.$commentid.'").load("editcomments2.php")';
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll keep this mind in the future if I run into a similar problem (ill mark this as the correct answer soon).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest *not* using `echo` to output HTML (in most cases anyway), but closing the PHP tag instead.

This becomes (edited with a loop example, see comments below):

```
<?php while ($commentid = $dbObject->dbMethod()): ?>
  <div id="commentinput<?= $commentid ?>">
  </div>

  <script>
  $('#commentinput<?= $commentid ?>').load('editcomments2.php');
  </script>
<?php endwhile ?>
```

Note that in this case, the `<script>` portion should probably be outside of the loop, with a jQuery selector matching all the comment inputs.

Comment: but what if I need to loop out html with values that come from a database? (That is what I'm doing)

Comment: @thespeciamone See my edit for an example using [PHP's alternative syntax for control structures](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php). You can alternatively use a template engine such as Twig, which is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

So besides all of the other answers, I found another solution to!
When echoing out js code, like

```
echo '$("#commentinput'.$commentid.'").load("editcomments2.php")';
//and
echo "alert('stuff')";
```

it might then print it out like: `$("#commentinput2").load("editcomments2.php")alert('stuff')` and the code will get confused. So lastly I need to added a semicolon to prevent the program from reading all my code as just 1 line:
`echo '$("#commentinput'.$commentid.'").load("editcomments2.php")';`